# In excel, can you create a named range from multiple values (linestring) within a single cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, named-ranges

I was wondering if I can make a named range from a linestring in a single cell, like "1,2,3,6,7" or "1-3, 6-7", instead of having to type each value in its own cell.

In column C of sheet A, I want to sum the values of column B if the values of column A exists in my named range "B_range", otherwise it will be 0. I use the formula:

```
=if(count.if(B_range,A2)>0,sumproduct(sum.if(A:A,B_range;B:B)),0)
```

"B_range" consists of C2:E2 in Sheet B, but if possible, I would like to define  "B_range" from the textstring values in B2 of sheet B.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Short answer is "no" (in spite of @JvdV's excellent answer) because 2,3,4 (for example) is a list of values, not a named range. A named range could be something like A2,A3,A4 or A2,A3,A4:A5 - they have to be valid cell references. You would need VBA to create such a named range from a cell containing (say) 2,3,4 and add it so that it was recognised by the Name Manager.

Answer (score 1):

This could be quite a tricky problem. A line like '2,3,4' not so much, but '1-3, 5,7` is allready much more problematic, let alone a combination of the two.

It is allready made easier if you'd have access to `LET()` and microsoft 365's dynamic arrays:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=LET(A,TRANSPOSE(MID(FILTERXML("<t><s>'"&SUBSTITUTE(E1,",","</s><s>'")&"</s></t>","//s"),2,LEN(E1))),B,--LEFT(A,FIND("-",A&"-")-1),C,IFERROR(--MID(A,FIND("-",A)+1,99),--A),D,MMULT((A2:A6>=B)*(A2:A6<=C),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A),,,0)),IF(D,SUM(B2:B6*D),0))
```

---

Variables explained:

- `A` - `TRANSPOSE(MID(FILTERXML("<t><s>'"&SUBSTITUTE(E1,",","</s><s>'")&"</s></t>","//s"),2,LEN(E1)))` will break up your initial string in an horizontal array. In our case `{2,3,4,6-8}`.
- `B` - `--LEFT(A,FIND("-",A&"-")-1)` will retrieve the number on the left of the hyphen. Note that we concatenate variable 'A' with an hyphen for this purpose. The result: `{2,3,4,6}`.
- `C` - `IFERROR(--MID(A,FIND("-",A)+1,99),--A)` will retrieve the number right of the hyphen. When no hyphen, the same as variable 'A' is returned: `{2,3,4,8}`.
- `D` - `MMULT((A2:A6>=B)*(A2:A6<=C),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A),,,0))` will calculate if any of your 'Nr.'s are to be found inbetween the previous two variables 'B' and 'C'. An vertical array is returned: `{0;1;1;1;0}`.
- `IF(D,SUM(B2:B6*D),0)` - Our final calculation is a simple `IF()` statement which will use `D` and spill the results down under 'Sum'.

I can get into much more detail, but the above should give you an idea of what happened here.

For those who find it interesting how to 'split' a string into an array, please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) link.

Comment: Thank you for a solution. A tricky problem with at tricky answer. Given my current skill level, and the desire to simplify my sheets and formulas, rather than to increase the complexity, I am going to read your answer as a "no" :) Thanks again.